# xslt2.0 Sorting with apply templates not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-stylesheet

i have seen several examples here on how to sort (re-order) a part of an xml with xslt 2.0
However i can't seem to get it working.

Example input file:

```
<example>
<field1>1</field1>
<field2>2</field2>
<fileheader>
    <headerfield1>1</headerfield1>
    <headerfield2>2</headerfield2>
    <headerfield3>3</headerfield3>
    <consol>
        <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
        <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
        <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
                <code>code</code>
                <value>50</value>
            </bespokehook>
        </file>
    </consol>
    <consol>
        <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
        <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
        <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
                <code>code</code>
                <value>20</value>
            </bespokehook>
        </file>
    </consol>
    <consol>
        <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
        <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
        <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
                <code>code</code>
                <value>40</value>
            </bespokehook>
        </file>
    </consol>
</fileheader>
```

what i want is to re-order the complete consol segment based on the value in the

```
                <bespokehook>
                <code>code</code>
                <value>20</value>
            </bespokehook>
```

I cant seem to get that working.
I used several examples from this site and others but no succes.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this

Tnx

Comment: So you want to reorder the `consol` elements inside of the `fileheader` element? Or the contents of `consol` elements?

Comment: does the posted answer to work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fileheader">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* except consol"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="consol">
      <xsl:sort select="xs:decimal(file/bespokehook/value)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms the input

```
<example>
<field1>1</field1>
<field2>2</field2>
<fileheader>
    <headerfield1>1</headerfield1>
    <headerfield2>2</headerfield2>
    <headerfield3>3</headerfield3>
    <consol>
        <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
        <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
        <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
                <code>code</code>
                <value>50</value>
            </bespokehook>
        </file>
    </consol>
    <consol>
        <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
        <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
        <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
                <code>code</code>
                <value>20</value>
            </bespokehook>
        </file>
    </consol>
    <consol>
        <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
        <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
        <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
                <code>code</code>
                <value>40</value>
            </bespokehook>
        </file>
    </consol>
</fileheader>
</example>
```

into the result

```
<example>
   <field1>1</field1>
   <field2>2</field2>
   <fileheader>
      <headerfield1>1</headerfield1>
      <headerfield2>2</headerfield2>
      <headerfield3>3</headerfield3>
      <consol>
         <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
         <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
         <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
               <code>code</code>
               <value>20</value>
            </bespokehook>
         </file>
      </consol>
      <consol>
         <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
         <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
         <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
               <code>code</code>
               <value>40</value>
            </bespokehook>
         </file>
      </consol>
      <consol>
         <consolfield1>1</consolfield1>
         <consolfield2>2</consolfield2>
         <file>
            <filefield1>1</filefield1>
            <filefield2>2</filefield2>
            <filefield3>3</filefield3>
            <filefield4>4</filefield4>
            <bespokehook>
               <code>code</code>
               <value>50</value>
            </bespokehook>
         </file>
      </consol>
   </fileheader>
</example>
```

Comment: If your problem is solved then you can accept the answer so that the question will be marked as solved.